# Can CruiseControl projects be put into queues?

Tags: c++, com, cruisecontrol

I have a few projects in CruiseControl that are related to one another.  Specifically, I've got a C++ COM component, a C# COM component, and a VB6 component.  I've also got some unrelated C# components (3 of them).

I'd like those 3 unrelated components to be able to use up to 3 threads, but keep the COM stuff only using 1 thread.  Something like the Queue feature of CruiseControl.NET.

Does anything like that exist for the old 2.8.4 CruiseControl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CruiseControl has the threads feature.

[threads](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#threads)

I'm thinking that can help you.